# Cómo cambiar el color de texto de una fila completa en PHP y MSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla que tiene tiene el campo ESTADO que tiene la siguiente información:

Por Registrar

Registrado

Sin Registrar

¿Cómo puedo hacer para cambiar automáticamente el COLOR DE TEXTO de TODA LA FILA según la información de ese campo?

Por Registrar: Color Verde

Registrado: Azul

Sin Registrar: Rojo

El siguiente código cambia el color de fondo directamente en el HTML en la etiqueta TR

```
bgcolor="<?php if($fila['ESTADO']=='Sin registrar') echo 'red';else echo 'Green' ?>"
```

Estaba pensando si se puede modificar el mismo para cambiar el COLOR DE TEXTO.

MUCHAS GRACIAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes probar algo así:

```
$setcolor = $fila['ESTADO']=='Sin registrar'? "red":"green";

echo '<tr bgcolor=$setcolor >';
```

Tal cual comentaron en caso de ser solo el texto, reemplazarías bgcolor por color..

Y dentro de la definición de setcolor podrías hacer tantas condiciones como desees.

Comment: Diria que ha preguntado por el color de texto, o sea, algo parecido pero con un `style="color:"`. Lo comento para que lo puedas poner en tu respuesta

Comment: Es verdad, lo agregué a la respuesta, muchas gracias!